# Property accessibility with multiple interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'll try to be clear. Here is the context:
I'm coding a library which will be used as a dynamic DLL in a different project.

I have 1 class which is internal and 2 interfaces:

```
internal class FinalClass : IFinalClass
{
    public string Libelle { get; set; }
}

public interface IFinalClass : IBase
{
    // some properties
}

public interface IBase
{
    string Libelle { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I load my library in my project, and I want to manipulate the IFinalClass type only.

I create a combobox with many IFinalClass items, and set the displaymember to "Libelle". The problem is: I can't see the value of "Libelle", indeed the assembly of FinalClass appears instead. (like if we are doing a ToString()).If I'm right, the combobox cannot find the property "Libelle".

But it's weird, because everything works fine if I cast the IFinalClass items to  IBase before filling the combobox datasource.

I'm very curious of what's happening in this case.

(Note that the class that implements "Libelle" is internal, so the other project doesn't know this type.)

Any idea? :)
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with: I can't see the value of "Libelle"?

Comment: I see the name of the assembly of the final class, something like "projectnamespace.FinalClass"

Comment: Can you post the code where you see the problem?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, there is no such thing as "diamond interfaces", only diamond inheritance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem

Comment: well ... Yes, you're right, I will correct it.

Comment: I have just edited my first post. The problem is now simplified.

Answer (score 4):

`Libelle` in the `AParentClass` is `private` by default.
But in `IBase` it is public by default.

Comment: Sorry, It is declared as Public in the abstract, ( I just edited the post )